# 6502 store instructions (STA, STX, etc.) and memory addresses

Tags: emulation, opcode, 6502

This really bothers me when writing my 6502/NES emulator...

The store instructions of the 6502 operate like this:

```
STA $2A78 - Store the value of the accumulator into memory address $2A78.
```

However, this instruction uses the absolute addressing mode, which should return the 8 bit value stored in memory `$2A78`. The `AND` instruction, does follow this rule:

```
(If $6A is stored in $2A78)
AND $2A78 - Perform a logical AND between the accumulator and the value stored in $2A78 (which is $6A)
```

Therefore in normal situations, the `STA` absolute instruction should store the accumulator value in the 8 bit zero page address which is stored in `$2A78`.
If it were to truly store the value in `$2A78`, shouldn't the addressing mode be immediate? - e.g. `STA #2A78`

Also, are there any other instructions that behave 'abnormally' like the store instructions?

Comment: What do you mean, "normal situations"? What do you mean, 'Therefore"? Your argument is not clear. So that we can address your misunderstanding, what reference are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may be confused about the use of the addressing modes. Absolute addressing mode simply means that the memory address to use for the operation immediately follows the opcode.

In both the cases you mention, `STA` and `AND`, this is the case.

However, *how* that memory address is used depends on *the opcode itself.* `STA` will use it as a location to store the accumulator. `AND` will use it to load a byte then use that byte to modify the accumulator. They are both absolute addressing mode despite that difference.

What you *appear* to be saying is that you expect a store to a memory address directly to use something like:

```
STA #$2A78
```

and I can see why you may think that more logically consistent, but that's not the way the CPU assembly language was designed, and it's unlikely anyone's going to go and fix it now :-)

Note that it makes little sense to `AND` an 8-bit accumulator with a 16-bit address value directly.

Comment: Ohhhh, that explains everything! This diagram that I was referring to (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6OHeG0FVYP8ZFNVd1p5emVfNnM/view?usp=sharing) was confusing to understand with store instructions - Now it makes sense :)